# How to make switches exclusive in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

In Shiny I would like to have two (pretty)Switches that I can leave:

- deselected,
- or selected only one at a time.

The desired behavior would then be that the 1st switch being `TRUE` automatically sets the value of the 2nd one to `FALSE`. And vice-versa.

I made an attempt with the following script, but it doesn't work as desired. In fact, I need to click **twice** on a switch before the value is correctly changed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Update the switch"),
    
    # Pretty switches 
    prettySwitch('one', 'one'),
    prettySwitch('two', 'two')
    
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent({input$one == TRUE}, {
        updateCheckboxInput(
            inputId = "two",
            value = F
        )
    })
    
    observeEvent({input$two == TRUE}, {
        updateCheckboxInput(
            inputId = "one",
            value = F
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with how you place the `observeEvent`, just make it dependant on the buttons, don't specify the condition in the first argument, you can do the rest inside the `observeEvent` itself. Also, a good pointer would be to stick with the full definitions for `bool`:`TRUE` and `FALSE`, try not to abbreviate it as a good practice

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Update the switch"),
    
    # Pretty switches 
    prettySwitch('one', 'one'),
    prettySwitch('two', 'two')
    
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$one, {
        if(input$one == TRUE){
            updateCheckboxInput(session,inputId = "two",value = FALSE)
        }
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$two,{
        if(input$two == TRUE){
            updateCheckboxInput(session,inputId = "one",value = FALSE)
        }
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: This works very well! I just had to change `updateCheckboxInput` into `updatePrettySwitch`.